# Apple watch text input language

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2

I am working on a translator app, and I am unable to use nuance speachKit for the watch, and decided to go for the default method:

```
- (void)presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:(NSArray *)suggestions
                         allowedInputMode:(WKTextInputMode)inputMode
                               completion:(void (^)(NSArray *results))completion;
```

now the problem I got into, it recognises text based on `[NSLocale currentLocale]` language, but I need to change them.

1 more thing, on strong tap (apply force) I get a language selection menu.

The question: 
a) any way I can call that menu before calling the text input method?
b) any way i change the system locale programmatically?
c) or at least edit the plist.info file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is currently no way to change the input language programmatically. `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions` uses the language of the currently selected keyboard on the iPhone.